# Protecting Persistent Data either by using Blackberry SIgning Authority Tool Or Some other mechanism

Tags: blackberry, signing, persistent, restrictions, code-signing-entitlements

We have developed an application in Blackberry 8830.
And we have stored the data in the Persistent Store. However, we would like to use some protection mechanism to secure the data.

We were using the following code :

```
    try{
        codeSigningKey = codeSigningKey.get(ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor().getModuleHandle(), 1234);

        _bill=new Vector();
        _bill=vtr;
        synchronized(billing)
        {
            billing.setContents(new ControlledAccess(_bill, codeSigningKey));
            billing.commit();
        }
    }
    catch(ControlledAccessException cae){
        System.out.println("Signing keys does not match: No Autorization to access data . ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
    }`
```

How could we protect the data by using the above mechanism, or some other way?

Answer (score 2):

To protect data you should use `ContentProtectedHashtable` or `ContentProtectedVector` as a container for your data instead of a plain `Vector` from your code sample. Then the container is put into the `PersistentObject`. Those containers have `reCrypt()` method that enables protection.

You should also know that to be able to use this approach you have to sign your app with your self-created key (the one that is referred as `codeSigningKey` in your code sample). For this you need to start another RIM tool - password-based file signer, point it to your .cod file and provide the password to access your key. Also note this key should be added to project resources.

Comment: Arhimed thank you, But still we are facing problems with the Blackberry Signing Authority Tool. Could you please guide us how to setup the Blackberry Signing Authority Tool. Is it just like, installing normally and following the steps or we need to install any apache server along with it? (Since as we observe after copying the xxx.key from the data folder to src folder of the project, we see some apache tomcat server, in the MDS of the simulator - Does it have anything to do with the implemetation)

Comment: I shall go through the steps we are following in packaging our project. 
1. Copy the xxx.key file from the "C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry Password Based Code Signing Authority\data" Folder
to the src Folder of the project.
2. Package the Project and then sign it using the "PasswordBasedFileSigner" as you have mentioned
3.a.  Then Sign the whole application with the General Signing Keys the .csi ones and then deploy
or
3.b. Then Directly deploy the application without signing with the General Signing Keys.
Watever we are facing prob like "prob since accessing secure api"

Comment: Blackberry Signing Authority Tool is just an app you have to install. I've never dealed with apache server during this meaning you don't have either. Your packaging steps should include signing with both General Signing Keys and "PasswordBasedFileSigner".